# How to bring options/choices div to optimal width?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, choices.js

I've setup this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-xnybol?file=style.css)

You can see in the styles.css file that I set the width of the option dropdown div to a fixed width of 650px, which works in that case

```
@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

.my_choices_inner {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: -2px;
  min-height: 44px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.choices__list--dropdown,
.choices__list[aria-expanded] {
  word-break: break-word;
  width: 650px;
}

.choices {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

But I would really like to have the width adjust automatically to the length of the options currently present in the dropdown div.

When I set the width to "100%", it will not overflow the container. I've also tried "fit-content" and "auto" to no avail.

What would I need to do to achieve this?

EDIT: To be precise: The text should not wrap, it should be in one line

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you expect? Do you want the text to stay on a single line and the div width to adapt?

Comment: Yes, exactly. This is what I want to achieve. I edited it in the OP

Comment: Please check below code adjusted link and let me know if it's working for you or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have revised the code, please check below link:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-vb71zr?file=style.css,index.js,package.json

Here, I have modified the CSS code to make the select div dynamic.

Also, I have added 1 more dummy value option for testing. Refresh the page and test it.
Please let the above example link and let me know if you find any issues.

EDIT: This is the essential part:

```
.choices__list--dropdown,
.choices__list[aria-expanded] {
  word-break: break-word;
  width: max-content;
}
```

Comment: yes, it's working mostly ... but it doesn't fully meet my requirements. There maybe several of those dropdowns on the same page and the options might be populated dynamically. And the value "8.4" is very arbitrary. Isn't there an easier and standard compliant way? I mean, usually, when you put a div with "inline-block" on a page, without further ado, it will adept its width to its content (see https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-8gmtaq). Why is this not possible here?

Comment: Please check above stackbitz link again, I have removed the jQuery and made is work using simple CSS

Comment: And it is as per standard way and dynamic way.

Comment: Please check and let me know if you find any issues.

Comment: That's it! Thank you. If you revise the wording of your answer a bit (removing jquery from it) I will gladly accept it :-)

Comment: Sure, Let me edit the answer.

Comment: I am glad it's working for you and I am happy